# Why Policy ARN is a required field to get policy unlike group and role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

Following is `GetRoleInput` struct used as input to `GetRole()` function to get aws role

```
type GetRoleInput struct {
  RoleName *string `min:"1" type:"string" required:"true"`
}
```

And following is `GetGroupInput` struct used to get aws group by calling `GetGroup()` method

```
type GetRoleInput struct {
  RoleName *string `min:"1" type:"string" required:"true"`
}
```

Now following is `GetPolicyInput` meant to get IAM managed policy

```
type GetPolicyInput struct {
 PolicyArn *string `min:"20" type:"string" required:"true"`
}
```

In `GetPolicyInput`, PolicyArn is used instead of policyName unlike previous two cases. So questions are

- Why PolicyArn is used for managed policy? Can policy name not identify a policy?
- Is there a way to get policyArn provided that we have policyName with aws API.

Comment: The AWS API expects policy ARN. There is nothing you can do about it. If the policy is created and managed by AWS, there will be no account number in the ARN. If it is a customer managed policy, you can form the ARN using the account number and policy name. To get the account number, you can run the following command: `aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text`. This API exists in all amazon SDKs.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some reason. My first guess was policy name might not be unique among managed policies.